# Groovy - parse through a database

Tags: python, database, groovy

I have a database where some devices have multiple entries, like

```
Device1: comment1
Device1: comment2
Device1: comment3
Device2: comment4
Device2: comment5
```

etc.
In groovy I define my query:

```
def query=resolve.resolve_db.rows("select u_sql from resolve.database_filter where u_name='Suppress Alerts - Hide Alerts' and u_queue='DATABASE'" as String)
query=query.u_sql[0].toString()
```

I want to parse throught all the inputs from devices, but it keeps getting stuck at comment1.
For example if i need to see if comment3 is for device1, it will return error because after the comment1 it does not search anymore if there are other inputs.

```
if (query.contains(device))  {

    def text=StringUtils.substringBetween(query, "$device%')", "(lower(alert.client)");
    if (text == null) text=StringUtils.substringBetween(query, "$device%')", "ORDER BY alert.created");
    def name=StringUtils.substringBetween(text, "lower('%", "%')");
```

How can i make it search through all inputs?

Exactly as I mentions above.

Answer (score -1):

[Sql.rows()](https://docs.groovy-lang.org/latest/html/api/groovy/sql/Sql.html#rows(java.lang.String)) function returns list of rows

in your case each row contains `u_sql` field

you could iterate all the rows with following code:

```
def rows=resolve.resolve_db.rows("select u_sql ...")
rows.each{row->
  println row.u_sql
}
```

Comment: Please don't post only code as answer, but also provide an explanation what your code does and how it solves the problem of the question. Answers with an explanation are usually more helpful and of better quality, and are more likely to attract upvotes.